# Django Expire logic for exactly 7 days

Tags: python, django, datefield

I currently have a `Promotion` table with a field `end_date` defines as:

```
end_date = models.DateField('date')
```

I would like to create a query where I can filter for all promotions that will expire in exactly 7 days.

How do I go about doing this? I've tried this with no luck:

```
from restaurant.models import Promotion 
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

expiring_soon = Promption.objects.filter(end_date = datetime.now()+timedelta(days=7))
```

Comment: Did you try `filter(end_date = datetime.now().date + timedelta(days=7))`?

Comment: `.filter(end_date = datetime.now().date() + timedelta(days=7))` works.

Comment: Yeah, I elaborated in my answer. The difference between dates and datetimes can be a little bit of a "gotcha".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I ran through a little dummy project and you're not far off, you're just not getting the **date** (as opposed to `datetime`) from `datetime.now()` and so you have to add an extra method call:

```
expiring_soon = Promotion.objects.filter(end_date = datetime.now().date() + timedelta(days=7))
```

Also note that `datetime.now()` gives you a non-localized `datetime` so you might see something where the results seem off by a day because UTC is ahead of/behind you.

Answer (score 0):

```
expiring_soon = Promotion.objects.filter(end_date =datetime.date.today() + relativedelta.relativedelta(days=7))
```